# Color bands in bar charts in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, colors, charts

Is it possible to obtain a bar chart like the one in this example:

[image: example]

(that is: I need to have vertical color bands to make "visually" group the bars for each horizontal axis' point.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by essentially creating one series of bars as your "background" then overlay the new series on top.  It seems a bit odd, creating a data series purely for coloring but it works.  It can be a bit tricky to visualize, but thankfully there's already a nice visual guide and detailed instructions for this here:

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ColoredVerticalBand.html